# This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted

Tags: .net, http, f#, f#-data

The following code, which uses the *Http* module of *FSharp.Data*, raised exception in function `setProxy` when the `Http.RequestString` was called. The similar code works when using `query` parameter instead of `body` on a different website. What can cause the problem? **BTW, it works when using a modified (for assigning proxy) previous version of Http module.**

```
let headers = [ UserAgent ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.["UserAgent"] ]
let setProxy (req: HttpWebRequest) = 
    req.Proxy <- WebProxy(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.["Proxy"], true)
    req // Error here
let cc = CookieContainer()

let body = HttpRequestBody.FormValues [
             "username", user; 
             "password", password; 
             "nothing.x", "21"; "nothing.y", "34"]
let html =
    Http.RequestString("https://..../CheckLoginServlet", 
        httpMethod = "POST", 
        body = body, cookieContainer = cc, headers = headers, 
        customizeHttpRequest = setProxy )
```

Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted.

Comment: why is this tagged `C#`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a **bug** in the *FSharp.Data* library. Looking through its [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/Net/Http.fs), we can extract code of our interest to something like:

```
let values = [ "id", "2"; ]
let req = WebRequest.Create("https://..../CheckLoginServlet") :?> HttpWebRequest
req.Method <- HttpMethod.Post
req.UserAgent <- "Magic"
req.AutomaticDecompression <- DecompressionMethods.GZip ||| DecompressionMethods.Deflate
let cookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
req.CookieContainer <- cookieContainer
req.ContentType <- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
let bytes = [ for k, v in values -> Uri.EscapeDataString k + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString v ]
                    |> String.concat "&"
                    |> HttpEncodings.PostDefaultEncoding.GetBytes
let f = fun () -> async {
    do! writeBody req bytes
    let req = customizeHttpRequest req
    let! resp = Async.FromBeginEnd(req.BeginGetResponse , req.EndGetResponse)
    let stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
    return! toHttpResponse
}
f()
```

the problem is in `writeBody` call **before** call to `customizeHttpRequest`, while its code is:

```
let writeBody (req:HttpWebRequest) (postBytes:byte[]) = async { 
    req.ContentLength <- int64 postBytes.Length
    use! output = Async.FromBeginEnd(req.BeginGetRequestStream, req.EndGetRequestStream)
    do! output.AsyncWrite(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
    output.Flush()
}
```

where `Async.FromBeginEnd(req.BeginGetRequestStream, req.EndGetRequestStream)` changes `HttpWebRequest.m_RequestSubmitted` flag, which is then checked by (like in many others) property setter of `HttpWebRequest.Proxy`. My suggestions:

1. Write your own method using `HttpWebRequest` directly,
2. Compile your own version of *FSharp.Data*, changing order of `do! writeBody req bytes` and `let req = customizeHttpRequest req` calls
3. Notify contributors of library to make a fix for this

Note: This can be easily reproduced in C# sample program:

```
private static async void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState; 
    Stream postStream = req.EndGetRequestStream(ar); // Here flag req.m_RequestSubmitted is true already
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("id=1");
    await postStream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    postStream.Close();
    req.Proxy = new WebProxy("localhost:8888", true);
    allDone.WaitOne();
}
private static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:64343/api/products");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.UserAgent = "Magic";
    req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("id=2");
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    req.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), req);
    allDone.WaitOne();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed on the latest version of F# Data